# iReport, error during spring loaded hibernate connection in netbeans plugin

Tags: java, spring, netbeans

i try to use iReport with an hibernate connection loaded using spring xml config file.

So, in netbeans wizard, i choose new datasource and i select "spring loaded Hibernate collection".
I set my xml spring file, but when i click test i have this exception:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Unexpected exception parsing XML document from class path resource [META-INF/spring.cfg.xml]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.FatalBeanException: NamespaceHandler class [org.springframework.context.config.ContextNamespaceHandler] for namespace [http://www.springframework.org/schema/context] not found; nested exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.context.config.ContextNamespaceHandler
```

The spring xml is ok beacouse al works great in application, the problem is when i try to use it for iRepor in netbeans plugin.

Documentation about jasper report using hibernate and spring are very very slightly.

**EDIT**
I added all spring-dependance jar in Tools->Options->iReport->classpath (i'm refering to netbeans, this is totaly undocumented...) and finally seem to load context, but now i have this excpetions:

```
WARNING [org.netbeans.ProxyClassLoader]: Will not load class org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.NamespaceHandlerSupport arbitrarily from one of ModuleCL@10eaeda[com.jaspersoft.ireport] and ModuleCL@19e3bdd[org.netbeans.libs.springframework] starting from SystemClassLoader[569 modules]; see http://wiki.netbeans.org/DevFaqModuleCCE
WARNING [org.netbeans.ProxyClassLoader]: Will not load class org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.NamespaceHandler arbitrarily from one of ModuleCL@10eaeda[com.jaspersoft.ireport] and ModuleCL@19e3bdd[org.netbeans.libs.springframework] starting from SystemClassLoader[569 modules]; see http://wiki.netbeans.org/DevFaqModuleCCE
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Unexpected exception parsing XML document from class path resource [META-INF/spring.cfg.xml]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.FatalBeanException: Class [org.springframework.context.config.ContextNamespaceHandler] for namespace [http://www.springframework.org/schema/context] does not implement the [org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.NamespaceHandler] interface
```

I think this is a problem of the netbeans plugin only and i can do anything :(

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Installing iReport standalone app all work good, so is a problem of iReport plugin in netbeans.